# Failed to send HTTP request to schema-registry

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to setup a local kafka-connect stack with docker-compose and I have a problem with my scala producer that's supposed to send avro messages to a kafka topic using schema registry.

In my producer (scala) code I do the following:

```
  val kafkaBootstrapServer = "kafka:9092"
  val schemaRegistryUrl = "http://schema-registry:8081"
  val topicName = "test"

  val props = new Properties()
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServer)
  props.put("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl)
  props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
  props.put("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer")
  props.put("acks", "1")
```

and my docker-compose script reads:

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.0
    hostname: kafka
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: zookeeper:2181

  producer:
   image: producer-app:1.0
   depends_on:
     - schema-registry
     - kafka
```

**EDIT**: now the schema registry seems to be up:

```
schema-registry    | [2021-01-17 22:27:27,704] INFO HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.17.Final (org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version)
kafka              | [2021-01-17 22:27:27,918] INFO [Controller id=1001] Processing automatic preferred replica leader election (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
kafka              | [2021-01-17 22:27:27,919] TRACE [Controller id=1001] Checking need to trigger auto leader balancing (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
kafka              | [2021-01-17 22:27:27,923] DEBUG [Controller id=1001] Topics not in preferred replica for broker 1001 Map() (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
kafka              | [2021-01-17 22:27:27,924] TRACE [Controller id=1001] Leader imbalance ratio for broker 1001 is 0.0 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
schema-registry    | [2021-01-17 22:27:28,010] INFO JVM Runtime does not support Modules (org.eclipse.jetty.util.TypeUtil)
schema-registry    | [2021-01-17 22:27:28,011] INFO Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@22d6f11{/,null,AVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler)
schema-registry    | [2021-01-17 22:27:28,035] INFO Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@15eebbff{/ws,null,AVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler)
schema-registry    | [2021-01-17 22:27:28,058] INFO Started NetworkTrafficServerConnector@2698dc7{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8081} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector)
schema-registry    | [2021-01-17 22:27:28,059] INFO Started @4137ms (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server)
schema-registry    | [2021-01-17 22:27:28,059] INFO Server started, listening for requests... (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain)
```

but prior to this, during the execution of the script I get:

```
schema-registry    | ===> Launching ...
schema-registry    | ===> Launching schema-registry ...
producer_1         | [main] ERROR io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService - Failed to send HTTP request to endpoint: http://schema-registry:8081/subjects/test-value/versions
producer_1         | java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Could this be due to some dependency issue? It's like it is running the producer before completely starting the schema-registry! I did put `depends on - schema-registry` for the producer ...

Comment: Do you need `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS`? https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/5.5.0-post/cp-all-in-one-community/docker-compose.yml#L42

Comment: When you launch the Docker Compose is the Schema Registry running? Can you connect to it from your host machine?

Comment: hello @OneCricketeer I've followed your example and simplified the docker-compose. Now the schema-registry seems to be up (see edit) but I still get the error (see Edit). Strange isn't it? Thanks so much guys

Comment: thanks @RobinMoffatt : yes (see my edit) it seems the schema-registry is running.

Comment: Yes this is confirmed! in my app I put a sleep(30s) and now the docker-compose up is showing I'm sending data: `schema-registry    | [2021-01-17 22:41:09,187] INFO 172.21.0.5 - - [17/Jan/2021:22:41:08 +0000] "POST /subjects/test-value/versions HTTP/1.1" 200 8  423 (io.confluent.rest-utils.requests)
producer_1         | [main] INFO ProducerLogger - test-0@0 written to partition 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the cause here was that your app was trying to call the Schema Registry before it had finished starting up. Perhaps your app should include some error handling for this condition and maybe retry after a backoff period on the first *x* failures?

Comment: Yes you're definitely right, but I was wondering: can't I put a condition in the docker-compose to execute the producer part only when the schema-registry is up and running? thanks

Comment: There various options listed here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else going through this, I was getting a connection refused error with my schema registry for the longest time. I have my schema-registry running on a docker container with a separate container for a REST API that is trying to use the schema-registry container. What fixed it for me was changing my connection URL in the REST container from `http://localhost:8081` -> `http://schema-registry-server:8081`.

Connecting to the Schema Registry in the REST container:

```
schema_registry = SchemaRegistryClient(
        url={
            "url": "http://schema-registry-server:8081"
        },
    )
```

Here's the schema registry part of my docker compose file

```
# docker-compose.yml

schema-registry-server:
image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
hostname: schema-registry-server
container_name: schema-registry-server
depends_on:
  - kafka
  - zookeeper
ports:
  - 8081:8081
environment:
  - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
  - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=zookeeper:32181
  - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry-server
  - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8081
  - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG=true
```